# Export a report and save in a location using JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I need to export a report and save it to a location specified, I have exported the report but I want to know how to save it in a file location, it is a doc or rtf format

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, filename);
exporter.exportReport();
```

of your conrete `JRExporter`. `jasperPrint` is of course your `JasperPrint`, and `filename` is the name of the target file (including directory)

Comment: Thank You for the answer, but it doesnt work, This is my code
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, "F://sample.rtf");

Comment: I have fixed the problem, now it exports and saves in doc, Thank you

Comment: Since Jasper uses JRRTFExporter for saving doc files, Is there any way to convert rtf to doc , or must we set any headers to convert it in doc in jasper?

Comment: ask that as another question. (I don't know)